# Converting For Loops To List Comprehensions

Tags: python, performance, list-comprehension

I was trying to understand List Comprehensions because I needed to improve performance on my project.

I believe this is how they work but please correct me if I am wrong.

To convert a for loop into a list comprehension the below for loop -

```
for A in B:
 if Condition:
  List.append(A)
```

would turn into

```
E = [A for A in B if Condition]
```

I didn't realize this was a duplicate. If the answers on this post were unsatisfactory, you can see the other post at the top of this one.

Comment: what does `==/in/>/<` mean?

Comment: That isn't a direct comparison, your for loop appends to an existing array of unknown state.

Comment: Don't expect any significant performance improvement just from changing an explicit for loop to a comprehension (which uses a loop). Carry out timing tests to compare. You can research ways of speeding loops in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand what you asked correctly, but generally if you have a for loop like this :

```
some_list = []
for A in B:
    if condition:
        some_list.append(A)
```

It's equivalent list comprehension is :

```
some_list = [A for A in B if condition]
```

If you have an else for your condition, it would be a little different. Consider the following example :

```
some_list = []
for A in B:
    if condition:
        some_list.append(value1)
    else :
        some_list.append(value2)
```

It would become like this :

```
some_list = [value1 if condition else value2 for A in B]
```